# select query for category data with parent child relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, select, tree

I have this db table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `inherit` enum('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `category`
--

INSERT INTO `category` (`id`, `parent_id`, `name`, `inherit`) VALUES
(1, 0, 'Fruits', 'N'),
(2, 0, 'Electronics', 'N'),
(3, 0, 'Furniture', 'N'),
(4, 0, 'Garden', 'N'),
(5, 1, 'Apples', 'N'),
(6, 1, 'Bananas', 'N'),
(7, 5, 'Green Apples', 'Y'),
(8, 5, 'Red Apples', 'N'),
(9, 2, 'Mobiles', 'Y'),
(10, 2, 'Televisions', 'N'),
(11, 9, 'Android', 'N'),
(12, 9, 'iPhone', 'Y'),
(13, 7, 'One Dozen Green Apples', 'Y'),
(14, 7, 'Two Dozens Green Apples', 'N');
```

There is another table where I keep user_id, category_id e.g. 
user_id 1000 can see 1 and 5, I put this info in the sessions so that my query becomes

```
SELECT *
FROM `category`
WHERE id
IN ( 1, 5 )
```

this query shows `Fruits > Apples` - all this works fine. But, I have marked "`Green Apples`" as `Inherit = 'Yes'` so user 1000 should see "`Green Apples`" too but not "`Red Apples`". If there are sub-categories under Green Apples marked as inherit = 'Y'... e.g. "One Dozen Green Apples" should be listed too!!

I thought to give UNION a go but can't figure out how to get more than 2 levels deeper ...

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM `category`
    WHERE id
    IN ( 1, 5 )

    UNION

    SELECT c.*
    FROM `category` c
    INNER JOIN `category` parent ON parent.id = c.id AND c.inherit = 'Y'
    WHERE c.parent_id
    IN ( 1, 5 )
) all_cats
```

What would you suggest to me? I am open table structure changes if that'd make querying any easier? thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try self join :

**EDIT:** I forgot to put the WHERE clause

```
SELECT
    a.name,
    b.name,
    c.name
FROM 
    category as a
LEFT JOIN category as b
    ON b.parent_id = a.id
INNER JOIN category as c
    ON c.parent_id = b.id
    AND c.inherit = 'Y'
WHERE
    a.id = 1
```

But the ideal solution is to have a recursive function that will do this since in that table you are describing a tree of categories . The query above is static it goes back 2 levels (2 subcategories) and from what i understand you need something dynamic .

Something like the function below :

```
public String getCategory(int categId){

    String sSql = "SELECT name FROM category WHERE id = " + categId ;
    String name = oDb.exec(sql).get("name");

    sSql = "SELECT id FROM category WHERE inherit = 'Y' AND parent_id = " + categId ;
    int nextCategId = oDb.exec(sql).get("id");

    if(nextCategId != null){
        return name + "," + getCategory(nextCategId);
    }else{
        return name;
    }

}
```

So assuming that Apples categ is inherited the result for `getCategory(1)` should be `Fruits,Apples,Green Apples`

Comment: Yes, I understand your point here. Actually, 1 & 5 above are selected by a function like that. For, example, User_Category table has only 5. but I select it's parent 1 by similar function above. I was just wondering if I could achieve with a query ... if not, I need to check that function again and see how to get inherit = Y ones

Comment: You cannot achieve this with a query due to the simple fact that you do not know from the start how many sub levels a category has ... but if you store this info (categ_id | number of sub levels) you can dynamically generate a query like above (number of joins = number of sub levels)

Comment: yes that correct that i don't know the level at the start ... however, I can amend the script to keep the level....

Comment: you have 2 choices ... choose whatever suits you best :)

Comment: I went for php solution to get the list of ids then run a simple mysql query to retrieve names etc. +1

Answer (score 1):

To get all categories with one query in mysql you will need as many self-joins as there are levels of depth in your category tree.
This is obviously impossible if your depth level is not limited.
However you can use a stored procedure to do id.

Assuming you have a table with categories for a user like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_category` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`category_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

with some data like:

```
INSERT INTO `user_category` ( `user_id`, `category_id` ) VALUES
( 1000, 1 ),
( 1000, 5 );
```

you can create a temporary table `cat_tree` storing id's of categories, initialize it with all parent categories for a given user_id from the user_category table and repeat self-joins down the tree as long as the last join inserted at least one category that wasn't there yet.

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS show_user_categories//
CREATE PROCEDURE show_user_categories( uid INT(11) )
BEGIN
  DECLARE found INT(11) DEFAULT 1;
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cat_tree;
  CREATE TABLE cat_tree (cat_id int(11) PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=HEAP;
  INSERT INTO cat_tree
    SELECT category_id FROM user_category
    WHERE user_id = uid;
  SET found = ROW_COUNT();
  WHILE found > 0 DO
    INSERT IGNORE INTO cat_tree
      SELECT c_child.id FROM cat_tree c JOIN category c_child 
      WHERE c.cat_id = c_child.parent_id AND c_child.inherit = 'Y';
    SET found = ROW_COUNT();
  END WHILE;
  SELECT cat_id FROM cat_tree;
  DROP TABLE cat_tree;
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

This procedure gives you a full list of category id's for a given user_id.

```
CALL show_user_categories( 1000 );
```

See a working example at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a618f/1).

Comment: I have managed to implement similar logic (which is in the procedure) using php. +1 for answer though. I have limited experience with procedures .. would this work e.g. $sql = "procedure here"; $db->query($sql); ???

Comment: Yes, it would work. The only problem may be your mysql user not having privileges to run SP's. Try comparing php and mysql solutions, mysql should be faster because there is no need to send all the data.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server:

```
;with CTE as
(
select id,name from category where id in(1,5)
union all
select c.id,c.name from category c join CTE ct on  c.parent_id=ct.id and c.inherit='Y'
)


select * from CTE
```

Comment: I have already tried that. but what about child category of Green Apple??

Comment: I have updated the table above (added two sub-categories of Green apples ... one with inherit = y other with no) the above query doesn't fetch "One Dozen Green Apples